# Printing all the values from multiple lists at the same time

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have 3 lists such as these

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
l3 = [7,8,9]
```

how do I get to print out everything from these lists at the same time ?
What's the pythonic way to do something like that ?

```
for f in l1,l2 and l3:
    print f
```

This only seems to be taking 2 lists into account.

Desired output: for each element in all the lists, I'm printing them out using a different function

```
def print_row(filename, status, Binary_Type):
    print " %-45s %-15s %25s " % (filename, status, Binary_Type)
```

and I Call the above function inside the for loop.

Comment: for f in l1,l2 , l3:
    print f

Comment: @cyberbemon, could you edit your post to include your desired output?  "everything from these lists at the same time" is ambiguous, and everyone's interpreting it slightly differently.

Comment: I don't think anyone has pointed out your misuse of the `and` operator.  `l1,l2 and l3` creates a tuple (becuase of the comma) the first item of of the tuple is `l1`.  The second item of the tuple is the result of `l2 and l3`.  Since they both evaluate to true, it returns `l3`.  You are effectively iterating over `(l1, l3)`.  Try this at the command line to see what's happening: `1,2 and 3`.  You'll get a tuple of `(1, 3)`.

Comment: Oops, mgilson addresses it in his answer.  I'll leave my comment as it may help to have it explained in different words.

Comment: @DSM I have added the desired output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you might want `zip`:

```
for x,y,z in zip(l1,l2,l3):
    print x,y,z  #1 4 7
                 #2 5 8
                 #3 6 9
```

What you're doing:

```
for f in l1,l2 and l3:
```

is a little strange.  It is basically equivalent to `for f in (l1,l3):` since `l2 and l3` returns `l3` (assuming that `l2` and `l3` are both non-empty -- Otherwise, it will return the empty one.)

If you just want to print each list consecutively, you can do:

```
for lst in (l1,l2,l3):  #parenthesis unnecessary, but I like them...
    print lst   #[ 1, 2, 3 ]
                #[ 4, 5, 6 ]
                #[ 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Comment: I think it might be the behaviour of "and" which is confusing him instead.  Usually we see people trying "a or b in seq"; this is the first time in a while I've seen "and" used here instead..

Comment: @DSM -- Honestly I had to test it out a little to figure out what was actually happening (e.g. whether `l1,l2 and l3` binds as `(l1,l2) and l3` or whether it binds as `l1,(l2 and l3)`.  It turns out the second one is the case (which in hindsight is obvious I suppose)...

Comment: If there is some way I can improve this answer, please leave a comment.  I'm always happy to edit and make things more clear / correct errors.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use `zip`, just add them together using the `+` operator. `l1 + l2 + l3` creates a new list that is the combination of `l1`, `l2` and `l3` so you can simply loop through that, like so:

```
for f in l1+l2+l3:
    print(f)
```

Your use of the `and` operator is incorrect. The other reason why your code doesn't work is using commas (like `l1, l2, l3`) creates a tuple, which is a container that now holds your 3 lists. So when you try to loop through `l1, l2, l3` it will loop through every element in that tuple (which are the lists) and not through every element in the lists as you intend.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Do:

```
for i,j,k in zip(l1,l2,l3):
    print i,j,k
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to achieve,

```
>>> #Given
>>> l1,l2,l3 = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
>>> #To print row wise
>>> import itertools
>>> for f in itertools.chain(l1,l2,l3):
    print(f,end=" ")


1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
>>> #To print column wise
>>> for f in itertools.izip(l1,l2,l3):
    print(*f,end=" ")


1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9 
>>>
```

or the following implementation which will work in Python 2.7

```
>>> for f in itertools.chain(*itertools.izip(l1,l2,l3)):
    print f,


1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It you're lists are not all the same length it is often better to use `map`:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> l3 = [7, 8, 9, 2]
>>> for x, y, z in map( None, l1, l2, l3):
...     print x, y, z
...
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
None None 2
```

Comment: `itertools.izip_longest` exists for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on top of Abhijit answer, you could use the itertools generator as the iterable within a list comprehension.

```
>>> [ n for n in itertools.chain(l1, l2, l3) ]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have 3 lists of equal length and you want to print out their contents as 3 columns, then how about zip() to connect the columns and a list comprehension to print() on each iteration:

```
[ print(row) for row in zip(l1, l2, l3) ]
```

The above will print repr's of tuple(s). If you want to format the values otherwise:

```
[ print("{} / {} / {}".format(*row)) for row in zip(l1, l2, l3) ]
```

Nobody said you have to *use* the output of a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use three *for* loops with *if* condition.

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
l3 = [7,8,9]
total = []
for x in range(len(l1)):
    for y in range(len(l2)):
        for z in range(len(l3)):
            if x == y and x == z:
                total.append(str(l1[x]) + " " + str(l2[y]) + " " + str(l3[z]))

print(total)

for i in range(len(total)):
    print(total[i])
```

Comment: well the 3 loops the time complexity is not very efficient.. `O(n^3)`..!